# GAS label visibility

Tags: google-apps-script

This code is supposed to change label visibility status...but it likes to stay hidden.  You can see I have tried to define *rlabel* two different ways.  I get an undefined error when using the code commented //.  I know it is executing the else statement. Thanks for your time...

```
function showDialog()  {
var app = UiApp.createApplication();    
var panel = app.createHorizontalPanel();
panel.add(label3);

...
var label3 = app.createLabel("Bad PIN");
label3.setId('BADPIN').setVisible(false);
app.add(panel);
var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
doc.show(app);
...
    }
```

ok, so the dialog parameters get passed to this function:

```
function respondtoSubmit(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  ...
  if (loftExists(PINValue)==true) {
     ...
     return app.close(); }
  else {  //show bad pin label 
     var rlabel =app.getElementById('BADPIN');
     rlabel.setVisible(true);        
     Logger.log ("rlabel.setVisible(true); just called");
     }
}
```

Comment: Is the `"BADPIN"` label being hidden somewhere else in the code? Maybe that piece of code is being called immediately after it is set to visible.

Comment: No, that is the last call to rlabel/Badpin.  The only call to `setVisible(false)` is in _ShowDialog_.

Comment: are you really SURE that your condition allows for calling `rlabel.setVisible(true)` ? I suspect it isn't ... use the logger to check like this `Logger.log('setVisible on label BAD PIN')` right after the `setVisible` call and you'll know exactly what happens

Answer (score 1):

The way you do it in your code, `label3.setId('BADPIN');` and lateron in the serverhander access it via `var rlabel =app.getElementById('BADPIN');` is the right way to do it. The other way, passing it thru `e.parameter`, can only be used to access the widget-value, not to manipulate the widget itself, and works only for those elements which have a setName-Method, which is not the case for labels (See [docu of addCallbackElement](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_serverhandler?hl=en#addCallbackElement)).

So the parts of the code you didn't show should have in showDialog():

```
  app.add(label3);
```

And, just to confirm that your else-part in the handler gets executed, add a Logger-output:

```
else {  //show bad pin label 
  var rlabel =app.getElementById('BADPIN');
  rlabel.setVisible(true); 
  Logger.log ("rlabel.setVisible(true); just called");
}
```

Check it, and if it still doesn't work, post your whole code, there must be another error then somewhere.

Comment: there is only one way to access a widget to change its visibility and it is by using its ID and `getElementById()`, the `e.parameter.name` can ONLY retrieve the widget value. I'm pretty sure you know that perfectly well but your answer is a bit ambiguous and could let people think both methods are useable in the scope of this post.

Comment: Clear as fresh water :-) or as crystal if you prefer... thanks for updating

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I've updated my original post to add code clarifications. Something funny is going on. The logger statement prints in the _else_. If I change _label3.setId('BADPIN').setVisible(true);_ in _ShowDialog_ it displays fine.  The only thing I can think of it somehow tied to the _return app.close();_ precedenting it in the _if_.  But I don't want the app to close under the else condition.

Comment: But you have to return the app from your handler. returning app.close() is not sufficient, because this returns the return-value of the close-method. There is a comment on the page https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_uiapp?hl=en, which says: `   return app;  // If you don't return the UiInstance, the change won't happen`

Comment: pbhd, you are a genius.  That was it...just needed to add `return app;` to the _else_.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `respondtoSubmit(e)` is called from some Handler in your UI, you must `return app;` at the end of the function. This is how GAS knows to update the view to the user.

Comment: Phil, i left out that line, but its there.

Answer (score -1):

You need to do `app.createLabel('Bad Pin').setName('BADPIN')` to be able to access the label on form submit. Setting the ID wouldn't be sufficient.

Comment: GTM, I had tried that, but _.setName_ is not valid syntax with labels.  It works with my textboxes.  Error msg:  **TypeError: Cannot find function setName in object Label.**

Comment: The code follows https://developers.google.com/apps-script/uiapp?hl=en,  **Using Server Handlers**

Comment: @GTM The ID is used to refer to the widget with `getElementById()`, the name is only useful to retrieve widget **values** in the handler function using event info parameter.